# What device drivers are needed to fully recognize a USB Keyboard?

Tags: linux, keyboard, input, keyboard-event

My problem is I have an embedded system normally headless.

It has a serial console I use for debugging, but will not be present in production.

It has no vga/graphics/monitor/whatever.

It doesn't have a proper keyboard or mouse.

So far, so good.

Now I need to connect a barcode scanner that works in "keyboard emulation" (i.e.: presents itself as an USB keyboard and acts accordingly).

I enabled several device drivers as modules:

- usbhid
- evdev
- hid_generic
- hid
- input_core

Scanner somehow works, meaning it gets initialized and generates Key events I can get reading `/dev/input/event0` (and they look OK).

What I'm missing is the complete decoding so that I can open a device and read characters (not scancodes). I expected the `hid-generic` module to pick up `input_event`s and generate characters to console.

What am I missing?

Comment: Normally the `keyboard` module handles translation from scancodes for VTs (though I am not sure how it decides which input-layer event sources to process), and there's a special X driver that does the same for input-layer event sources. I am not sure if you can use `keyboard` without a VT, possibly you can create a dummy framebuffer.

Comment: @dirkt: I have CONFIG_INPUT_KEYBOARD set, but no specific kbd selected as they do not seem to pertain to USB keyboards. I also have CONFIG_USB_HID (loaded as a module), CONFIG_TTY and CONFIG_VT (compiled in), but keys from USB kbd show up *only* as events and don't get decoded. Any hint welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I have **all** I need.

Problem is keystrokes will *not* be sent to `/dev/console` (connected to serial line); they are however correctly decoded and available reading `/dev/tt0` (current virtual terminal).

I have no idea (and neither interest, truly) if and how to redirect them to `/dev/console` so they get merged together as it happens on a desktop PC.